# How to properly set up local and remote git repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh

I have a local rails app that is a local git repo. I want to push that to my remote webserver and than be able to push changed files to that.

I tried just transferring all the files over via SCP and then on my local run a `git clone ssh://...` but when I try to push files from local to remote I get the `[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)` error.

All the stack questions around this error don't work for me (i.e. I can push but no files actually show up on the remote server, or I still get the error).

How do I set it up so that I can

a) push files from local to remote

b) have a full copy to run the rails server from on the remote?

EDIT: cloned repo .git/config

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://10.1.150.24:/home/mwerner/dashing/.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: show your `.git/config` of cloned repo

Comment: here is useful link http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/

Comment: some more useful link http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: so i managed to pull / push from the remote bare repo. But lets say I want to have the app running, do i need to git clone to a separate directory and keep git pulling to keep it up to date every time I update the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ssh access:

```
git clone git+ssh://remote_pc/path_to_folder
```

for gaccess to a git-server:

```
git clone user@server:path/to/git/repo
```

for github:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo
```

Comment: the first two still give me the error about the non-bare repository, and the third doesn't apply because I am not using github

Comment: @Killerpixler also try specify `--bare my_project`